# Where is the documentation for the GitHub Copilot VS Code extension's advanced settings?

Tags: vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I use the official copilot extension for VS Code
I find the advanced setting in the setting option but i don't find any documentation of all possible option that  can use in that section:

```
"github.copilot.advanced": {
}
```

someone know where to find it?

Answer (score 2):

Found this here [github-copilot-explorer](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thakkarparth007/copilot-explorer/4a572ef4653811e789a05b370d3da49a784d6172/muse/github.copilot-1.57.7193/package.json)

##### Disclaimer: Mileage may vary, warranty ended right before I clicked the post button

```
"secret_key": A string field for entering a secret API key. This key could be used for identification and authorization purposes when connecting to GitHub Copilot. This field does not have a default value.

"length": An integer field specifying the maximum length of generated code in tokens. A 'token' in this case would be an individual component of the code, such as a keyword, identifier, operator, or punctuation mark. The default value is 500 tokens.

"temperature": A string field for adjusting the 'temperature' parameter in the AI's sampling function, which affects the randomness of the AI's output. Lower values make the output more deterministic, while higher values increase randomness. This field does not have a default value and ranges from 0.0 to 1.0.

"top_p": A numerical field setting the 'top_p' or nucleus sampling parameter, which specifies the cumulative probability threshold for token selection. By default, this value is set to 1, meaning that all tokens with non-zero probability could be considered for generation.

"stops": An object field that allows setting per-language stop sequences. These could be sequences of tokens that tell the AI to stop generating further code for a specific language.

"indentationMode": An object field for controlling indentation block termination on a per-language basis. For instance, you could set "python": false to disable automatic block termination for Python code.

"inlineSuggestCount": An integer field that determines the number of inline suggestions to fetch. By default, GitHub Copilot would fetch 3 inline suggestions.

"listCount": An integer field that sets the number of solutions to display in the GitHub Copilot interface. The default value is 10 solutions.

"debug.showScores": A boolean field controlling whether to show scores in the sorted solutions. By default, this feature is turned off.

"debug.overrideEngine": A string field for specifying an alternate engine name. This could be used for testing or debugging purposes and does not have a default value.

"debug.overrideProxyUrl" and "debug.testOverrideProxyUrl": These string fields allow you to specify alternate GitHub authentication proxy URLs. The former is for general use, and the latter is specifically for running tests. Both fields do not have default values.

"debug.filterLogCategories": An array field for specifying which log categories to display. If the array is empty, all log categories will be displayed.
```

Comment: im trying to config it aswell and didnt find official doc yet, meanwhile: https://g.co/bard/share/d6b9fec920fb

Answer (score 2):

Rather than give you the actual setting descriptions, I'll tell you how to find it yourself, since the settings can change over time.

Basically, you want to find the [extension's manifest file](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest) (package.json) and read the stuff under [the `contributes` > `configuration` property](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration). The only slight challenge here is that the extension isn't open source (in which case you could just go to its repository homepage and find the package.json there).

So instead, if you've installed the extension, find the extension under the `.vscode/extensions/` directory in your user home directory. There should be a directory there with a name starting with its extension id (`Github.copilot`), and its package.json will be in there. Alternatively,
if you don't want to install the extension for some reason, go to [the extension's marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot), click the "Download Extension" link, which will download the extension's VSIX file, rename the filename extension from .vsix to .zip, unzip it, and read the package.json from there.

Also, if you've installed it already, the setting descriptions may or may not be in the defaultSettings.json pseudo file (I'm not sure- I haven't checked). You can open that file with the `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).